# Any Javascript Editor Control for .NET (like in Visual Studio)?

Tags: c#, javascript, ide, editor

Is there any Javascript Editor Control like in visual studio? Thanks...

Comment: Can you tell more what you actually want? 
Sorry, just never used visual studio for myself, so can't get what is like it and what not :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/)

Comment: uh... "Free, Open Source and Cross Platform

Download Aptana Studio for Windows, Mac, or Linux. Both the standalone and Eclipse plugin distributions are free, open source software."

Comment: I've use Aptana on a couple projects, it's a great product. In the JavaScript space it's the best editor I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pay for Visual Studio, you can use [Visual Web Devleoper Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/). If you are looking for intellisense for javascript, this does not have it, but [Aptana](http://www.aptana.org/) does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a rich editor, plus dockable windows etc, then you might be able to combine tinymce with [this](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/05/30/Advanced-docking-using-jQuery.aspx).